# Label do formulário não é mostrado na página #django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Criei um formulário para cadastro de clientes e na classe meta declarei as fields e seus respectivos labels. Porém o label 'CPF' referente ao campo 'n_cpf' não mostra na página, aparece apenas **N cpf**.
Como faço para rotular 'CPF' nesse campo?

**forms.py:**

```
from django import  forms
from .models import Cliente

from localflavor.br.forms import BRCPFField

class ClienteForm(forms.ModelForm):
    n_cpf = BRCPFField()
    class Meta:
        model = Cliente
        fields = ['name', 'last_name', 'n_cpf', 'birth_date', 'height', 'weight', 'active']
        labels = {'name':       'Nome', 
                  'last_name':  'Sobrenome',
                  'n_cpf':      'CPF',
                  'birth_date': 'Data de nascimento',
                  'height':     'Altura',
                  'weight':     'Peso',
                  'active':     'Ativo',
                  }
```

**cadastro.html:**

```
{% extends 'app_web/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <p>Adicione um novo cliente:</p>
    <form action="{% url 'app_web:novo_cliente' %}" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button name="submit">Adicionar</button>
    </form>
{% endblock content %}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Poderia mostrar a pagina html onde esta sendo exibido o formulário?

Note que você pode exibir o label digitando no html, por exemplo {{ form.cpf.label_tag }}

Comment: Ok amigo coloquei o html. Estou começando em django, no formulário html eu uso apenas esse duplo colchete '{{ }}' pra interpolar a variável.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente o seguinte:

```
n_cpf = BRCPFField(label='CNPJ')

<form action="{% url 'app_web:novo_cliente' %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for field in form %}
        <p>
            {{ field.label_tag }}
            {{ field }}
            {{ field.help_text }}
            {{ field.errors }}
        </p>
    {% endfor %}
    <button name="submit">Adicionar</button>
</form>
```

Deste modo você ainda irá renderizar o form sem ter que escrever todo o form, porém, facilitará que você mecha no formulário, como realizar if's dentro do form por exemplo.